# Kiddushin 8b: Making kiddushin vs fulfilling a mitzvah

Tags: talmud-gemara, maseches-kiddushin

[Kiddushin 8b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.8b.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) asks if a man says "Mikudeshes li" to a woman and gives her a loaf and she says "Give it to a poor person" she is not engaged - even if the poor person is supported by her - because she could say that he has a chiyuv to give to the poor.

But, just above that they say that if he tries to be engaged with a loaf and she says [give it to a dog](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.8b.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that is chasing her she may or may not be engaged (On the one hand, she benefits because she is saved; on the other hand she can say that **he has a chiyuv to save her**)

On the case of the chasing dog, the Gemora concludes תיקו but on the case of the poor person it concludes she is not engaged.

Why is the dog-case unresolved and the poor person case is not?

Comment: As I was writing the question it occurred to me that it could be because in the case of the dog she gets a benefit - so there is an alternative way to interpret the situation. However, at least in the case of the poor person who she supports: Doesn't that mean giving the loaf to the poor person is to her benefit?